# confusing with tl494 application circuit

Tags: tl494

According to [tl494 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tl494) on application section.
For  buck converter, they use error amplifier with 101x gain to control swithching duty cycle and then for curent limit, they use high gain error amp (70 dB, internal, about 3162x gain) to control current (seem like it shut down immedietly when detected over current). Then I got very confusing

1. It's look like close-loop propotional control will it got steadt-state error with high load?
2. can it regurate current as CC?
3. Why it don't need compensater as shone in [Loop Stability Analysis of Voltage Mode Buck Regulator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjmsoqkpcHqAhVXyDgGHZUNDvgQFjASegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fpdf%2Fslva301&usg=AOvVaw04XL7_OakDIybyxaidEVRh)

Note also [Designing Switching Voltage Regulators With the TL494](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf?ts=1594336669243) don't mention to compensator at all.

Comment: I suggest you install Grammarly to correct your English.  Then show your design specs

Comment: If you use a current sensor with 50~100mV drop instead of a scaled down voltage, you can design for CC instead of CV.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I just try to learn things and get confuse.

Comment: See figure 9. R13 is current-sensor. R1+R2 setup current limit. R1+R2 can be replaced to variable 3-pin resistor 5k. You can regulate current.

Comment: 3. If you need of compensator connect it to to 1-2 pin of error amplifier (for figure 9 example). "Control Voltage" is pin#3.   Also see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511214/why-is-there-no-frequency-compensation-required-in-tis-tl494-example-buck-regul pin3 - compensator added.  see http://320volt.com/en/bike-motors-control-circuit/ C2, R3,R6,R7,R8 is compensator.